# SELECT from Function that return CURSOR

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, cursors

I would like to select from a function that return a  SYS_REFCURSOR Type value.

for example :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_funtion (
        my_param IN VARCHAR2)
     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  IS
     l_return   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
           OPEN l_return FOR
                SELECT last_name, first_name
                  FROM employees
                  WHERE id = my_param
              ORDER BY employee_id;
     RETURN l_return;
END my_funtion;
```

I would like to do something similar to this :

```
select * from  my_function('id015');
```

or even :

```
select alias.last_name from  my_function('id015') alias;
```

Comment: Interesting read here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365?tstart=0

Answer (score 5):

You could try using
`select * from table(xmlsequence( myfunc() ))` . In this case you get xml in columns.

Or try this example to extract fields from your refcursor

> ```
> select extractvalue(column_value,'/ROW/FIRST_NAME') first_name
>      , extractvalue(column_value,'/ROW/LAST_NAME') last_name
> from table(xmlsequence(f()));
> ```
>
> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
> :--------- | :--------
> Donald     | Duck     
> Mickey     | Mouse
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d0dc55ed812e0dc2d7b6f1b0d2c058a)*

PS. Note about xml overhead.

Comment: Does this solution closes the sys_refcursor internally?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
variable x refcursor 
set autoprint on 
exec :x := my_function('id015')
```